# Alert Dialog not showing in tablet but working perfectly in phone.

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, tablet

I have an alert dialog.

I can show it as a part of 2 activites.

**Activity A** - `Normal Class Extending Activity`.

**Activity B** - It is an empty activity. It also has `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` mentioned in it manifest declaration.

If I am showing it as a part of A it is working perfectly.

But if I am showing it as a part of B it not showing up at all. 
All I am see is a blank activity with "`Application Name`" in the center of the screen.

Any ideas what the issue might be?
Also, the dialog has a linear layout shown in it. If I am using `linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)` while showing the dialog would there be any issues if I am using it in a tablet?

Comment: Why not simply post some bits of code instead of explaining it ?

Comment: post log cat details.

Comment: @Bartdude -  yeah buddy.. even i would like nothing better.. but i cant.. i m sitting in office right now.. which doesnt permit me to post code.

Comment: Well that's going to be a problem then. You should suggest some improvements in that field to your admins, I can presume you're not the only one to have that kind of problem... being forbid to post code makes it very hard fo you to find help, especially here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention the following in Manifest For all activities in project

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
```